# How to install ie9 (Internet Explorer 9) on Windows 7 despite 80092004 error

Tags: internet-explorer-9, windows-7-x64, bsod, windows-update

Unfortunately, for testing purposes I need to use Internet Explorer 9, and I've followed the MS Answers super helpful trouble-shooting guide, and scoured google, and still not managed to install it.

Also tried IETester, Utilu IE Collection, Triple Booting a trial edition of windows.

All the forums, eventually terminate at "Format disk, reinstall windows" solutions or have no reply. Reinstalling windows is not a viable option!

I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 Service Pack 1 (Dual booted).

Windows update fails with:

```
"WindowsUpdate_80092004" "WindowsUpdate_dt000"
```

:According to "get help with this error". However, if you look at the event logs, it says:

```
0x80070643
```

:which is confusing, as it is not the same error. Why, windows, why?

There is a microsoft fix it you can download which cleans up after failed updates (why is this not done automatically by windows update??) and after running it, restarting in safe mode with networking, and installing it directly from a standalone installer, ie9 "installs", but if you run it and click on "help > about" it says its IE8, and then at some point after the computer gets BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death) and when it restarts, poof! Its IE8 again.

So, how does one install ie9?

Comment: FYI Apple's Safari installed easily on Win7 and runs fine 0_0

Comment: Try running windows updates and install all updates except for IE9 first. Then reboot. Then try installing IE9 again

Comment: Windows updates all already done, except for Bing Desktop (optional). Rebooting has been done after each fixing attempt I made.

Comment: A colleague recommended http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/ as another workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***I finally found a solution !***

Run cmd.exe as Administrator:

```
FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*9.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"
```

(From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2579295/en-us#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways)

Tested on:

- Windows 7 Professional N SP1

Symptoms were:

- 80092004 Windows Update Error
- Manual installation(IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe) failed install.
- Windows Features in Add/Remove showed "Internet Explorer 9", but starting IE showed version 8 in about.

Answer (score 2):

Astonishingly (i.e after trying so many different other suggested fixes) the approved answer fixed my problem installing IE9, but not IE10, so I tried changing the 9 in the command to a 10, and after that (without even a restart), the IE10 standalone installer suddenly worked.

Here's the command I used for IE10 - fixed the dreaded 9C59 error for me at least:

```
FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows can be pretty bitchy about having what it considers to be the wrong version of it's software installed.

Perhaps your best answer would be to install **XP Mode**.  As a user of Windows 7 Professional x64, you are eligible to download and install Windows XP Mode for free.

XP Mode is actually Microsoft's PC Emulation software "Virtual PC" complete with **a full and fully LICENCED version of Windows XP** already installed and set up.  The purpose of XP Mode is to provide an inconvenient (yes, I mean inconvenient) way for people to run old 16 bit and incompatible 32 bit programs while encouraging them to "upgrade" away from perfectly good software (especially command line software) and force them buy new 64 bit stuff. (With this one move, Microsoft eliminates 30 years of software they find undercuts DRM, and their vision for, and control of Windows.)

It's a bit of a memory hog, can take a while to launch, and tries to install itself to run in the background, but right click and close the icon in the taskbar a couple times and it'll stop doing that.

One really nice thing about it is that you can setup several different machines with different stuff installed on each one, without it using up all the drive space that installing separate OS's would. Plus, if you hose one, you can delete it's `.vsv` file and be back to a working copy, minus whatever you did to hose it (unless you made a change to the os and rebooted to a hosed os.)

Anyway, it can be found here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

You'll need to be running a legit versin of Windows 7 Enterprise, Professional, or Ultimate, and using Internet Explorer to be able to download it.

Because, you know, nobody else has legitimate reason to run 16 bit programs. (Did I rant?)

Comment: Cool suggestion, but if it's truly running XP, doesn't that mean you can only run up to IE8?

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that the top answer works with IE11 as well on windows 7, here's the adjusted code for 11:

FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*11.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"